# How to normalize the direction to check if the player is able to move?

Tags: 2d, collision-detection, mathematics

I have a room with 4 walls along the x and z axis respectively. My player, who is in first person (therefore the camera), should have collision detection with these walls. I'm relatively new to this so please bare with me. I believe the way to do this is to calculate the direction and distance to the wall from the camera and then normalize the directions. However, I can only get this far before I don't know what to do. I think you should work out the angle and direction your facing?

Here `_dx` and `_dz` is the small buffer in front of the camera.

```
float CalcDirection(float Cam_x, float Cam_z, float Wall_x, float Wall_z)
{
    //Calculate direction and distance to obstacle.
    float ob_dirx = Cam_x + _dx - Wall_x;
    float ob_dirz = Cam_z + _dz - Wall_z;
    float ob_dist = sqrt(ob_dirx*ob_dirx + ob_dirz*ob_dirz);

    //Normalise directions
    float ob_norm = sqrt(ob_dirx*ob_dirx + ob_dirz*ob_dirz);
    ob_dirx = (ob_dirx)/ob_norm;
    ob_dirz = (ob_dirz)/ob_norm;
```

Can anyone explain in layman's terms how I work out the angle?

Comment: Are you aware of raycasting?

Comment: do you mean, from the camera position you have, say a bounding box to help when you hit the wall?

Comment: No. Take a starting point, for example, the head of your character and cast rays around his field of view. Each time a ray intersect something, store the distance from the starting point and the intersection point. However i'm not sure this is the best way to handle collision of a moving character in 3D (in fact i'm sure it's not a good way to go) but it looks like what you are trying to do.

Comment: Also what are you trying to do? Because i'm wondering why are you trying to detect collision this way? It's for a *real* 3D game or are your trying to do something similar to Doom or Wolfenstein (using raycasting to draw a 3D representation of a 2D world) ?

Comment: it could be said to be similar to doom, what im looking for is collision detection with the walls around the maze, which im sure has to be done by having say a bounding rectangle in direction of the camera and seeing if this touches a wall within a certain parameter and therefore i can not go any further.

Comment: Similar to doom in which manner? Does your world is defined in 2D and then rendered in 3D? I mean by a simple 2D array or something similar? If it's the case you could do the detection collision process directly in 2D.

Comment: at the moment its just a room. so 4 walls, in a 3d space but im only testing the x and z axis.

Comment: Then http://www.euclideanspace.com/threed/animation/collisiondetect/index.htm if you want to see different ways to handle collision detection in 3D space.

Comment: are you going to have a "box" based geometry in your level ? ( walls ) or will you have walls that are placed in diferent angles ? depending on that, you can choose a collision system.

also keep in mind that you should give your camera a bounding box to prevent the player to be able to look through walls if the camera is right in front of the wall.. ( the camera will have variables for min- and max-render distance, where min-distance should be small enough depending on the size of your bounding box of the camera )

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a well documented problem. What you want isn't the distance from the camera to a specific point on the wall `(Wall_x,Wall_z)`. Rather, you can find the point on a wall which is closest to the camera, at any time. [This article](http://blog.generalrelativity.org/actionscript-30/collision-detection-circleline-segment-circlecapsule/) should tell you all about the math involved, even though it's for ActionScript.

Once you know the point which is closest, finding the distance and direction is trivial. Actually, you can look at the whole thing as collision detection between a circle (around the camera) and a line (a wall) in 2D (seen top-down, ignoring the y dimension).